# How to arrange 3 UIButtons side-by-side in swift3 programmatically

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, constraints

I want to arrange 3 UIButtons side-by-side in swift3 programmatically,

they should be equal width regardless of device. please be details code with constraints .

here I have tried with constraint , all buttons are in centre together. this is my code,

```
 let addToWishListBtn: UIButton = {

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Add to Wish List", for: UIControlState())
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "service_icon"), for: UIControlState())
    btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: UIControlState())
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addToWishListBtnTarget), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 50, 40, 0)
    btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)
    btn.backgroundColor = .yellow
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()
func addToWishListBtnTarget() {
    print("add  to wish btn target")
}

let emailToFriendBtn: UIButton = {

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Email to Friend", for: .normal)

    btn.setImage(UIImage(named:"service_icon"), for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    btn.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(emailToFriendBtnTarget), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 50, 40, 0)
    btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return btn
}()
func emailToFriendBtnTarget() {
    print(" email to friend target")
}

let shareBtn: UIButton = {

    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Share", for: UIControlState())
    btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "service_icon"), for: .normal)
    btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: UIControlState())
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareBtnTarget), for: .touchUpInside)
    btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 50, 40, 0)
    btn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.backgroundColor = .purple

    // button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    btn.backgroundColor = .green
    return btn
}()
func shareBtnTarget() {
    print("share btn target")
}



    view.addSubview(addToWishListBtn)``
    view.addSubview(emailToFriendBtn)
    view.addSubview(shareBtn)


    addToWishListBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 380).isActive = true
    addToWishListBtn.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    addToWishListBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 125).isActive = true
    addToWishListBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    emailToFriendBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 380).isActive = true
  //  addToWishListBtn.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    emailToFriendBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    emailToFriendBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 125).isActive = true
    emailToFriendBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    addToWishListBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 380).isActive = true
    addToWishListBtn.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    addToWishListBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 125).isActive = true
    addToWishListBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

[image: this is three button picture]

Comment: What you have tried so far and what issues you are facing... please upload the code

Comment: pl. take a look at edited ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give following constraints..

- btn1 leading to its superview
- btn2 leading to btn1 trailing
- btn3 leading to btn2 trailing
- btn3 trailing to its superview
- btn1 equal width to btn2
- btn2 equal width to btn3
- btn1 top to its superview
- btn2 top to its superview
- btn3 top to its superview
- for all 3 buttons you also need to give height constraints.

You can give constraints by `constraintsWithVisualFormat` or `constraintWithItem`.

**EDIT:**

Take a look...

```
//all 3 buttons will be in views dict.
    let views = ["btn1" : btn1, "btn2" : btn2, "btn3": btn3];

    // align btn1 from the top
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-8-[btn1]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views));

    // align btn2 from the top
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-8-[btn2]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views));

    // align btn3 from the top
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-8-[btn3]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views));


    //horizontal constraints
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-8-[btn1]-8-[btn2]-8-[btn3]-8-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views));

    // height constraint if you want to give
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[btn1(==30)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views));

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[btn2(==30)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views));

    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[btn3(==30)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views));

    //equal width for all 3 btns
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: btn1, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: btn2, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: btn2, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: btn3, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
```

Comment: can you me help to answer this question. i want to detect one button in tableview cell by click on button. here is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48970198/how-to-detect-one-button-in-tableview-cell?noredirect=1#comment84948065_48970198

Comment: check answer of that question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1) create constraints (Little long and harder)

2) Use Stack View

If your app runs ios9+ You can use `UIStackView`

so create  `UIStackView` programatically 
and add 3 buttons to it  it will automatically adjust width accordingly

Here is an example

```
let labelOne = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
labelOne.text = "Hello"
labelOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

let labelTwo = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
labelTwo.text = "There"
labelTwo.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

let myStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [labelOne, labelTwo])

myStack.distribution = .fillEqually
myStack.axis = .horizontal
```

Enjoy ...

Hope it helps to you

Comment: what is output ? ,